# Why are screenshots taken with ffmpeg uneven in time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following ffmpeg command to take screenshots every 5 seconds of a video file that is 85 seconds long:

```
ffmpeg -i out2.mp4 -vf fps=1/05 img%03d.jpg
```

I get 18 files When I look at the resulting screenshots, they are 5 seconds apart, but the first frame starts around 3 seconds, the second is then 8 seconds, and so on. How do I get it to start with the very first frame, and then go 5 seconds apart on subsequent frames?

Answer (score 0):

You're the using the `fps` function, whose primary use is to change the framerate, not select specific frames. When using it to reduce framerate, it uses a regular cadence to retain frames. For 1/5, that's the middle frame in a 5-second segment.

Use the `select` filter.

```
ffmpeg -i out2.mp4 -vf select='lte(mod(t,5),0.01)' -vsync 0 img%03d.jpg
```